# how make a DropDown option based on option selected in first dropdown

Tags: flutter

I  have two dropdowns. the first permit to choose the country and the second the city that depends on the country.
Both are widgets build in different  files but used in the another same file.
my difficulties: How to retrieve the choice of countrie and how to transmit it when i am calling the city widget to use it to retrieve the cities of the chosen country because my variable  _maselectionpays that contains the choice of the country is not declared in this widget

```
                          //debut
                 Listepayswidget(),
                 Listevillewidget(pays:_maselectionpays),
```

EDIT:

my code of widget country (pays)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';


class Listepayswidget extends StatefulWidget {
 Listepayswidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _ListepayswidgetState();

}
class _ListepayswidgetState extends State<Listepayswidget> {

   String _maselectionpays;
   List data=List();
  //List _allville= new List();
   Future<String> getpays() async {
  // paradisimo.000webhostapp.com
  final response = await http.post(ressource);

  var resbody= json.decode(response.body);
  setState((){
  data=resbody;
   });
  print (resbody);
  return "success";
 //datab=data.toString();
   }

    @override
   void initState(){
    super.initState();
    this.getpays();

}
  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new Container(

              child: 

              new DropdownButton(


                items: data.map((item){
                  return new DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: new Text(item['libelle_pays']),
                    value: item['code_pays'].toString(),

                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (newVal){
                  setState(() {
                   _maselectionpays=newVal; 
                  });
                },
                value: _maselectionpays,
              ),
            );




  }
}
```

The code of widget city(ville) is similar than the code of widget country(pays).

This is my code of statefulwidget when I call widget pays

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:paradisimmo/utilitaire/combo_offre.dart';
import 'package:paradisimmo/utilitaire/combo_pays.dart';




class EnregistreroffrePage extends StatefulWidget {
   EnregistreroffrePage({this.username});
final String username;
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _EnregistreroffrePage();
}

class _EnregistreroffreData {
  String email = '';
  String password = '';

}

class _EnregistreroffrePage extends State<EnregistreroffrePage> {
  bool monVal = false;
  bool tuVal = false;
  bool wedVal = false;
  int _radioValue1 = -1;

 void _handleRadioValueChange1(int value) {
    setState(() {
      _radioValue1 = value;

      switch (_radioValue1) {
        case 0:

          //correctScore++;
          break;
        case 1:

          break;
        case 2:

          break;
      }
    });
  }

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  _EnregistreroffreData _data = new  _EnregistreroffreData();

  void submit() {
    // First validate form.
    if (this._formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save(); // Save our form now.

    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //final Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Enregistrer une offre'),
      ),
        body: Center(
            child: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 8.0,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                           //debut
                  Listepayswidget(),
                  Listevillewidget(pays:_maselectionpays),
```

Comment: Could you share more of the code.

Comment: Added some more information in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of `StatefulWidget` for your input form. When you select a *country*, then trigger `setState()` and that will rebuild the *city* drop-down widget. You can find more examples on [`StatefulWidget` here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive). Here is [sample code](https://github.com/flutter/samples) from google.

> Read your newly added code and here is what i think:

`_maselectionpays` .a.k.a country need to be accessed from the statefullwidget city(Listevillewidget). It is needed there so you can rebuild the city upon **country selection**. There is a couple of ways of doing this, but the easiest is to make  `maselectionpays` a variable inside `EnregistreroffrePage`, then pass it to `Listepayswidget(maselectionpays)` and to `Listevillewidget(maselectionpays)`. When it is changed you call `setState` inside `Listepayswidget` and you shall use it inside `Listevillewidget` in the `DropdownButton`. Would have used it as an `key` in a `HashMap<key, value> data`, the value would of course be a list of citys and the key is countries. So if the key changes, the country then the city-list changes. Therefor Flutter would re-build the element.

For a better management of this could you should look into the [BLoC-pattern](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-bloc-with-streams-6ed8d0a63bb8), it's less code. Or look [into RxDart](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UwewEk-9nWk), that uses `observables` and `Streams` for handling changes, also this uses less code.